# Cannot load my regular expression from JSON correctly

Tags: python, json, regex

*Case closed: I was loading it correctly after all, but other, sub-optimal behavior in my code caused me to think that I wasn't.*

---

I'm loading a regex string from JSON:

```json
"version_scheme": {
    "type": "tuple",
    "re": "data-file=\"kitty_portable-(.*?)\\.exe\""
}
```

However, using `re.findall(...)`, I get `[]` back on a haystack like this (this would be a `text` attribute of a GET request made using `requests` module):

```html
<a href="https://www.fosshub.com/KiTTY.html?dwl=kitty_portable-0.74.4.10.exe"
                        data-file="kitty_portable-0.74.4.10.exe"
                        aria-label="Download kitty_portable-0.74.4.10.exe Windows portable"
```

Comment: What is the text you are searching?  What are the current and expected outputs?

Comment: I've put a summarised version at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The double quotation marks `"` need to be double- (`\\"`) or triple-escaped (`\\\"`).

The literal dot `.` needs to be quadruple-escaped (`\\\\.`).

#### Working backwards

The raw string you want:

```
r'data-file="kitty_portable-(.*?)\.exe"'
```

The string you want:

```
'data-file="kitty_portable-(.*?)\\.exe"'
```

The string you want stored as JSON:

```
'data-file=\\"kitty_portable-(.*?)\\\\.exe\\"'
```

- Each of the double quotation marks `"` needed to be escaped with either a double backslash or a triple backslash.
- Each of the two backslashes preceding the literal dot needed to be escaped with a single backslash each.

Comment: Thanks and welcome! So it turns out I was storing/loading it correctly then. I considered deleting the question but will leave it to honor your contribution and Tim's.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex should certainly work in Python:

```py
inp = 'something data-file="kitty_portable-0.74.4.10.exe" something'
matches = re.findall(r'data-file="kitty_portable-(.*?)\.exe"', inp)
print(matches)  # ['0.74.4.10']
```